# Bootstrap modal does not open

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal in my html file that I want to trigger with a button.
My button is inside a table. This is the code of my button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" >
            <!-- [routerLink]="['/function', bfunc.AName]" -->
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
          </button>
```

And this is my modal-code in the same html-file:

```
<!-- line modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

    <!-- content goes here -->


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-delete hidden" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="delImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-red" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Delete</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I hit the button nothing happens.
I checked the console but there are no errors

Can anyone help me please?

EDIT: 
I have imported these scripts in my `index.html`

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you import the js and css for bootstrap modal?? Also jquery??

Comment: see my edit above are there any missing?

Comment: I tried copying your code into the example at: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h and it worked. It may be you are missing some resource.

Comment: ok, i am not sure which ones I am missing. Can u help me? see my edit which scripts I imported

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap css? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the bootstrap css `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Remeber that for bootstrap you need both `css` and `js` files. I like to get it from the [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned you need to ensure that all resources (js, css, jquery) are imported in order to get the modal to work. Here's a simple html file with the modal code and all resources in the head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> Launch demo modal </button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"> ... </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```